# How to fill all fields from a form with uiautomator

Tags: python, android-uiautomator

Currently I'm trying to fill all fields from a form using Python + [uiautomator](https://github.com/xiaocong/uiautomator)

**My Code:**

```
d = UIDevice(adb.deviceList[0].device)

last_item_exists = d(text='Memo').exists

while not last_item_exists:
    print "Searching for fields on screen"
    fields = d(className = 'android.widget.EditText', focusable = True)
    for field in fields:
        if not (field.text == '0' or field.text == '50'): #Skip fields with 0 or 50
            print "Writing on the field"
            field.click()
            d.press(0x0000001d, 0x00001000)
            d.press('del')
            field.set_text('50')
        else:
            print "Skipping field"
    print "Searching for Memo field"
    last_item_exists = d(text='Memo').exists
    print "Scrolling down"
    d(scrollable=True).fling()

d(text='Confirm').click()
```

**The Problem:**

Depending on device resolution, this error may occur:

```
uiautomator.JsonRPCError: JsonRPC Error code: -32002, Message: com.android.uiautomator.core.UiObjectNotFoundException: UiSelector[CLASS=android.widget.EditText, INSTANCE=9, FOCUSABLE=true, RESOURCE_ID=com.salab.ABRT:id/task_info_item_count]
```

This is happening, because when I click on the last visible field field, the screen sometimes scrolls down a bit and the top field is not visible anymore.

Is there a workaround for this kind of problem, or I must change my logic(Can't think about anything right now...) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UiAutomator only sees what is visible on the screen at each moment. So if you scroll down (or the app does) then it can't interact with it.

You either change your logic or you swipe the screen up and down verifying if everything is filled and, if not, fill it.

Comment: Hi Inês, thank for your answer. Is there a way to check if the screen is changed ? Because the problem is on this line: `field.click()`. When the field is clicked, the screen scrolls down a bit because the field isn't totally visible

Comment: Directly with UiAutomator you can't know if the screen changed. However, you can use UiAutomation (note the difference) to read the contents of the screen and compare them as you wish.
Nevertheless, if you fill the fields by the order they appear in you should be fine.
One last thing, I've dealt with problems interacting with objects when they are not completely drawn in the screen and so I verify the bounds to see if they are completely inside the screen before interacting with it. I don't know if this extra info is of any use to you though.

Comment: Your comment helped me a lot.
I think the easiest approach is to scroll down if the field is not fully visible. What do you think ?

Comment: I think that's your best choice :)

Comment: There is yet another option:
You can click the field (which will make it scroll on its own) and then find the object again. Now it will be fully visible.
Both should work just fine.

Comment: Ok Inês, I think I got it... Thank you very much..

Can you give just another help how to check the bounds ? Because the EditText is inside a SrollView, I've got the ScrollView bounds and the EditText bounds, but I could not figure out how to know if the EditText is fully visible or not

Comment: Having the UiDevice d, you can do d.getDisplayHeight() and d.getDisplayWidth(). With those you have the max y and x bounds. The minimal x is 0, the minimal y... Well it should be 0 lol but you have the notification bar (unless it's a fullscreen app) and so if you know the top y value of the root of the screen you know the minimal y of your app.

Comment: You can find everything about the UiDevice API here http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/test/uiautomator/UiDevice.html